# Django: "'Blogmodel' object is not iterable"

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-views

i have error 'Blogmodel' object is not iterable my

**view.py**

```
def blog_list(request):
    articles = Blogmodel.objects.all()
    args = {'articles':articles}
    return render(request,'blog.html',args)

def blogDetail(request, slug):
    article = Blogmodel.objects.get(slug=slug)
    args = {'article':article}
    return render(request,'blogdetail.html',args)
```

**url.py**

```
path("blog/",blog_list, name="blog_list"),
    path("blog/<slug:slug>",blogDetail, name="blogDetail"),
```

**htmlfile**

```
{% for tt  in article %}
<div class="content_box">
    <div class="content_l left">
        <div class="horoscope_box_big">
            <div class="blog_img1">
                <img src="https://horoskopi.ge/storage/blog/250-ოთხი ზოდიაქოს ნიშანი ყველაზე მაღალი ხელფასებით.png" alt="ოთხი ზოდიაქოს ნიშანი ყველაზე მაღალი ხელფასებით" />
            </div>
            <h1 class="blog_title1"><!-- სათაურის-->
<div class="blog_descr1"><h1>Info</h1>

<p> {{ tt.body }}</p>

</div>
        </div>
    
    
{% endfor %}
```

when i try without for loop it's working , what is reason ?

Comment: You can loop through "articles" queryset, "article" is a single object

Answer (score 1):

Get() method is going to return BlogModel object so thats why it is not iterable, since for printing article you are using loop so thats why you need to write a queryset object thats why you need to use filter() method.

Check this out:-

```
def blogDetail(request, slug):
    article = Blogmodel.objects.filter(slug=slug)
    args = {'article':article}
    return render(request,'blogdetail.html',args)
```